# How to fetch data from API using Python

Tags: python

I have to get data from rest API using Python. How to send headers to retrieve data from API. Is there any module for requesting data from API.

Comment: The `requests` module is useful for taking to the web. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 7):

Try `requests` it has two method `get()` and `post()`

Please try:

```
import requests
import json 
res = requests.get('paste your link here')
response = json.loads(res.text)
```

Answer (score 3):

Previous answers have covered the idea behind how to fetch data from an API using python. Requests library is a natural selection if you want to achieve this.

Documentation and ref: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Installation: `pip install requests` or https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/install/#install

Coming to the last part - how to send headers to retrieve data from API? 
You can pass `headers` as `dictionary` to the request.

```
url = 'https://api.github.com/some/endpoint'
headers = {'user-agent': 'my-app/0.0.1'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Now you have the `response` object in `response` variable; now it's up to you what you want to achieve. e.g. If you want to see what is the response body as String;

```
print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes python has `requests` lib to make a call to POST and GET methods

e.g.

```
import requests

url = 'web address'
params = {'key':'value'}
r = requests.get(url = url, params = params) 
response = r.json()
```

Answer (score 0):

At first install 'request' library for making HTTP requests.
pip install requests

```
import requests

userInput = str(input("Enter Poke Character: ")) #take user input
userInput = userInput.lower() #covert user input in lower case
def pokeGenerator():
    if userInput:  # if userInput is true
      pokeApiUrl = requests.get(f'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/{userInput}') 
                                                  #store api url in a variable

      if pokeApiUrl.status_code == 200:  #check api status

         data = pokeApiUrl.json() #convert into python dict
         print(f"Name: {data['name']}") #print name

         print("Abilities")
         for ability in data['abilities']: #loop through ability. Because it is a nested dictionary
            print(ability['ability']['name'])

      else: # if status code is not 200
         return print("Character not found")

 print(pokeGenerator())
```

if the status is 200 then the result will be:

```
Enter Poke Character: ditto
Name: ditto
Abilities:
limber
imposter
None

Process finished with exit code 0
```

if the status is not ok then:

```
Enter Poke Character: dobubjwdbuwdb
Character not found
None

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use the [requests module](https://pypi.org/project/requests/)

```py
# pip install requests
import requests

# Send a GET request to a website
res = requests.get(
    "https://www.example.com/", # The URL of the API you want to access
    params={"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}, # The parameters you want to pass to the API (like "?key=value" at the end of the URL)
    data={"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}, # The data you want to send to the API
    headers={"header1": "value1", "header2": "value2"}, # The headers you want to send to the API
    cookies={"cookie1": "value1", "cookie2": "value2"}, # The cookies you want to send to the API
    auth=("username", "password"), # The authentication credentials you want to send to the API (some websites require this)
    timeout=5, # The maximum site response time (in seconds) 
    allow_redirects=True, # Whether or not to follow redirects
)

# Send a POST request to a website
res = requests.post(...)

# Send a PUT request to a website
res = requests.put(...)

# Send a DELETE request to a website
res = requests.delete(...)


if res.status_code == 200:
    output = res.json()
    print(output)
```

If for some reason you want to use a standard module, you can do this with [urllib](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/urllib.html)

```py
import urllib.request
import json

response = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.example.com")

if response.getcode() == 200:
    output = json.loads(response.read())
    print(output)
```

If you need to perform this action in an asychronous function, you can use [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/)

```py
# pip install aiohttp
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get("https://www.example.com") as response:
            if response.status == 200:
                output = await response.json()
                print(output)
                
asyncio.run(main())
```